# Trying to multiply between two functions?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner Python programmer and I'm creating a calorie counter as a lab. What I'm trying to do is take the integer value of the calories in a list and multiply it by the integer value of the quantity in a list.

The code can be found below

What I want to do is basically

```
calories = int((conv(carbs, "c") + conv(fats, "f") + conv(protein, "p") * qtyList[c]))
```

but it says `c` is not defined (this is because I'm not doing this in the displayList function, but I don't know how to incorporate c into the addItem function locally, or how to do it at all in the first place.)

For more info and a tl;dr of the program and what it needs to do:

- Welcome menu
- display options `(a - add item, d - delete item, l - display list, q - quit)`
- when it's `a`, receive string item name, int item quantity, int values for conversion to calories, return calories as an int to global variable, then multiply quantity*calories for total item calories
- `d` - delete an item from the list via its position in the list
- `l` - display the list.. simple
- `q` - quit

I'd love to know if anyone can help me with this one problem, though, not the whole thing. Thanks.

```
# New Lab 7

# define lists
itemList = []
qtyList = []
calsList = []
totalCal = 0

def conv(grams, kind):
    if kind == "f":
        return grams * 9
    else:
        return grams * 4

def dispMenu():
    print ("a - add item")
    print ("d - delete the item")
    print ("l - display the list so far")
    print ("q - quit")

def addItem():
    carbs = 0
    fats = 0
    protein = 0
    calories = 0
    item = input("Item name: ")
    if item.isspace() or len(item) == 0:
        print("item must have a proper name")
        return None  # get me outta here
    try:
        qty = int(input("quantity: "))
        if qty <= 0:
            print("quantity must be a positive number")
            return None
    except:
        print("That was not a valid integer.")
        return None
    carbs = int(input("How many grams of carbs are displayed on your item? "))
    fats = int(input("How many grams of fats are displayed on your item? "))
    protein = int(input("How many grams of protein are displayed on your item? "))
    global calories
    calories = int((conv(carbs, "c") + conv(fats, "f") + conv(protein, "p") * qtyList[c]))
    calsList.append(calories)
    itemList.append(item)
    qtyList.append(qty)
    print("Your item contains", calories, "calories.")
    global totalCal
    totalCal += calories
    return totalCal

def dispList():
    if len(itemList) == 0:
        print("\nThere are no items in your list\n")
    else:

        print("\n\n\nThe items in your list are")
        print("Itm\tItem\t\tQty\tCals")

        totalQty = int(0)
        for c in range(len(itemList)):
            print(str(c+1)+".\t" + itemList[c], "\t", qtyList[c])
            totalQty += qtyList[c]

        print("Total calories:\t{}".format(totalCal) + ".\n\n\n")



def delItem():
    if len(itemList) == 0:
        print("\nThere are no items in your list to delete\n")
    else:
        print("Please choose the item number to delete")
        dispList()
        choice = int(input("Delete item > "))

        if 1 <= choice <= len(itemList):
            del itemList[choice - 1]
            del qtyList[choice - 1]
            print("Item Deleted")
            dispList()
        else:
            print("\nThe value is out of range\n")




# start the program
print("Welcome to Clinton's Calorie Counter!")
dispMenu()
while True:

    choice = input("> ")

    if choice == "a":
        addItem()
        dispMenu()
        continue
    elif choice == "q":
        dispList()
        print("Goodbye!")
        break
    elif choice == "l":
        dispList()
        dispMenu()
        continue
    elif choice == "d":
        delItem()
        continue
```

Comment: you can pass `c` as an argument to the function. This is a simple response as I do not understand where `c` came from

Comment: c comes from the dispList function, where it displays every item in the list as long as C is not less than or equal to 0 or greater than the length of the itemlist

Comment: There are so many comments on your code. I think it is better to submit it for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Since you don't call `dispList` until _after_ `addItem`, it makes no sense to use a variable from `dispList` when you're adding. Also, `c` is the iteration variable in the `for` loop, so which value of `c` would you be using?

Comment: @sobolevn CR is for **working code**, which the OP's isn't yet.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, you are right. After he has it fixed.

Comment: Don't add "answers" to the question; if this is solved, accepting an answer is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you mean:

```
calories = int((conv(carbs, "c") + conv(fats, "f") + conv(protein, "p") * qty))
```

More than that, you mean:

```
calories_per_item = int((conv(carbs, "c") + conv(fats, "f") + conv(protein, "p"))
calories = calories_per_item * qty
```

Other wise the computed number is: `carbs + fats + (protein * quantity)`

That is, using the quantity you just requested from the user. Later in the code you'll append it to `qrtList`.

Comment: okay your second response seems to work fine but I am also getting another error in my list function where trying to print calsList[c], it says it can't convert an int to a string implicitly, but it has no problem doing that with the quantity, which are both wrapped in an integer. do you know why this is? i've had this problem for a while and google hasn't been much of a help. thank you for your response, though

Comment: You can't straight up add strings and ints eg. `"string" + 1`. You either need convert the int to a string (`"calories: " + str(calsList[c])`) or print the string and int as separate items (`print("calories:", calsList[c])`).

Answer (score 1):

Use `qty`:

```
calories = int(conv(carbs, "c") + conv(fats, "f") + conv(protein, "p") * qty)
```

You are filling your list later with `qty`: `qtyList.append(qty)` Using the current value should work.